# How do I create an array based on an existing array, that I have created?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have created an array by breaking a sentence into characters(including punctuation, and spaces).  I would like to create another array based on the characters in in this one. Here is the code that I wrote.

```
def split(arr, size):
    arrs = []
    while len(arr) > size:
       pice = arr[:size]
       arrs.append(pice)
       arr   = arr[1:]
   arrs.append(arr)
   return arrs

def main(): 
x_mat = [list(word.rstrip()) for word in result] 

for rows in x_mat: 
    if len(rows) == 3 :
        rows = rows.append(' ')

myarray = np.asarray(x_mat)
m = len(myarray)
n = len(myarray[0])

numx_mat = np.zeros([m, n])

for j in range(len(myarray)) :  
    if( 97 <= ord(myarray([j,1])) <= 122):  
        numx_mat([j,1])  == 1 
    elif( myarray([j,2]) == '.' or '?' or '!') :
        numx_mat([j,2]) == 1 
    elif( myarray([j,3]) == ' ') :
        numx_mat([j,3]) == 1 
    elif(65 <= ord(myarray([j,4])) <= 90 ): 
            numx_mat([j,4]) == 1 
    else :
            continue 
main()
```

The error message that I get is the following:
Traceback (most recent call last):
in main
    if( 97 <= ord(myarray([j,1])) <= 122): 
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

myarray is the 2d array that I have created consisting of characters including punctuation and spaces from the string by considering 4 characters at a time, in the order (1234, 2345, ... etc) I would like to create a new array with 1's and zeros where I am looking for a specific pattern in the order of the characters. ( If the first character is a lower case letter the new array has a 1 in the first position, if the second character is a space, the new array has a 1 in the second position etc).  SO how do I check that the first entry (1,1) is a lower case letter in the existing array?

Comment: The error means that the argument to `ord` is not a `callable`. It must be a one-character string (run `python -c "print help(ord)"` in your terminal). What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Also, some advice about asking clear questions: 1) *Abstract the problem*: the problem rarely requires giving a detailed explanation of what the application is. A stripped down sample is usually enough. 2) *Make sure your code is properly formatted*: otherwise we have to guess where indents happen.

Comment: I want to see if each 'row' of the array that I created is of the form: a lower case letter, an end of the sentence punctuation, a space and a capital letter, helping me detect the end of a sentence and the beginning of the next one.

Comment: I will edit the problem and make it more presentable.

Comment: Can you clean up the indentation? `main` appears to be incorrect. Is everything between the line `def main():` and the call to `main()` supposed to be within the function `main()`?

Comment: @ChrisFreeman   yes. everything is within the function main()

Comment: You can break up a string into an array using `list(string)`. `>>> string = "This is a sentence. Followed by a bang! And a Question?"
>>> list(string)
['T', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'a', ' ', 's', 'e', 'n', 't', 'e', 'n', 'c', 'e', '.', ' ', 'F', 'o', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'w', 'e', 'd', ' ', 'b', 'y', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'b', 'a', 'n', 'g', '!', ' ', 'A', 'n', 'd', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'Q', 'u', 'e', 's', 't', 'i', 'o', 'n', '?']`

Comment: Yes, that is what I did.  Then I pick the first four characters, then the next characters 2-5 etc in creating the array from this string.  For each of the four choices of characters I would like to form a pattern of 1's and zeros.  (a pattern of 4 ones would indicate to me the end of a sentence). But I don't know how I can create the new array of ones and zeros.

Comment: I was expecting the 'for' loop in main would help me do that, but I was not successful.

Comment: Use the 'islower' method of 'str' instead

Comment: @romeric I tried using myarray([j,1]).islower() ==TRUE and i still get the same error message.  I am not sure if my syntax is correct for this

Comment: The error tells you that you are calling a numpy array like a function. Remove the braces `()` from `myarray` i.e. just write `ord(myarray[j,1])`

Answer (score 0):

Working outside of `numpy` for a moment, there are other approaches you may wish to consider.

#### using re.match to parse string

```
def gen_array(string):
    new_array = []
    for x in range(0, len(string)-3):
        if re.match(r'[a-z][?.!]\s[A-Z]', string[x:x+4]):
            new_array.append(1)
        else:
            new_array.append(0)
    # append trailing three zeros
    new_array.extend([0, 0, 0])
    return new_array
```

Which produces an array of 1's and 0's:

```
>>> string
'This is a sentence. Followed by a bang! And a Question?'
>>> gen_array(string)
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

The "1" is at the "e" in "sentence" and the "g" in "bang".

#### using re.finditer to get offset matches as an array

```
>>> string
'This is a sentence. Followed by a bang! And a Question?'
>>> results = list(re.finditer(r'[a-z][?.!]\s[A-Z]', string))
>>> results
[<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(17, 21), match='e. F'>, <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(37, 41), match='g! A'>]

>>> for match in results:
...     print(match.group(), "at", match.span())
... 
e. F at (17, 21)
g! A at (37, 41)
```

The character classes (sets) can be adjusted as desired for Unicode or other punctuation characters.